# Testing spring context without xml

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing, web-applications

I use java based configuration in web application:

```
public class SpringInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

  @Override
  public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.getEnvironment().getPropertySources().addLast( myMethod() );
    ctx.scan("com.xxx.xxx");

  }
}
```

how can i test it?

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(????????????)
public class PersistenceConfigurationTest {

    @PersistenceContext EntityManager entityManager;
    @Autowired DataSource dataSource;

    @Test
    public void infrastructureShouldBeAutowired() {
        assertNotNull(dataSource);
        assertNotNull(entityManager);
    }
}
```

**additional remark:**
there were some answers with advice how to create another context based on same config class. i can't do it because i fine tune the created context (adding some properties). i've just added the code

Comment: Need some clarification, you want to know how to test your `SpringInitializer` class? or do you want to know how to load `@ContextConfiguration` for a test using java config?

Comment: no, i want to test my dao. but i'm building my context manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will answer your question:
https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10199?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel

In one word: What you want to do is not possible yet. Same here. I use the WebApplicationInitializer to use a CustomBeanFactory and achieve logger ctor injection. But now i am not able to inject that loggers into my test objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.xxx.xxx")
public class Config {}

public class SpringInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(Config.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {Config.class})
public class PersistenceConfigurationTest {

    @PersistenceContext EntityManager entityManager;
    @Autowired DataSource dataSource;

    @Test
    public void infrastructureShouldBeAutowired() {
        assertNotNull(dataSource);
        assertNotNull(entityManager);
    }

}
```

Comment: i've just update my question (sorry for not being more specific). i can't use this solution because it doesn't let me configure the context

Answer (score 0):

This blog post should answer your question almost exactly (I just hope you are using Spring 3.1).

http://blog.springsource.org/2011/06/21/spring-3-1-m2-testing-with-configuration-classes-and-profiles/

Scroll to the **Integration Testing with @Configuration Classes** part

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: i've just update my question. there is no solution in this article

Comment: I don't understand your question now.. you say you want to unit test, or test your dao; but you also want to load the entire context? Shouldn't you load only what you want to test and test it?